# Creating a singleton per worker on Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, singleton

Suppose that I want to map a RDD using a object that is somehow expensive to create. I want to have one of this object per worker/thread, and it must be created before processing the items of the RDD partition on each worker.

My solution was:

```
    final Function0<ModelEvaluator> f = () -> {

        if (ModelEvaluator.getInstance() == null) {
            ModelEvaluator m = new ModelEvaluator(script);
            ModelEvaluator.setInstance(m);
        }

        return ModelEvaluator.getInstance();
    };

    JavaPairRDD<Double, List<Service>> results = cartesian.mapToPair(
            (t) -> {
                try {
                    double val = f.call().evaluateModel(t);
                    return new Tuple2<>(val, t);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
    );



public class ModelEvaluator {

  private static ModelEvaluator instance;

  public static void setInstance(ModelEvaluator instance) {
    ModelEvaluator.instance = instance;
  }

  public static ModelEvaluator getInstance() {
      return instance;
  } 
...
```

In this case, the "ModelEvaluator" object parses a script then use a list of "Service" objects to configure the model parameters in order to compute the associated response metric for that parameter configuration. But I don't want to parse the script each time that a RDD row is processed.

I also configured my cluster to create a process for each cluster, and each process will spawn only one worker, since it'll be problematic accessing a singleton instance with mutable state by multiple workers in the same process at the same time.

Is there a more elegant solution for my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a `Broadcast` variable.  This will allow you to create an object on the driver, and it will be sent once per worker as it is needed.

```
final Broadcast<ModelEvaluator> model = jsc.broadcast(new ModelEvaluator(script));

JavaPairRDD<Double, List<Service>> results = cartesian.mapToPair(
        (t) -> {
            try {
                double val = model.value().evaluateModel(t);
                return new Tuple2<>(val, t);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return null;
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked like a charm. I needed to make the "ModelEvaluator" class Serializable and configure some fields to be transient to avoid problems. And I needed to use some logic to perform a lazy initialization of the object, instead of initializing it on the constructor.

Comment: @DaniloM.Oliveira can you please share the final version of your code?